# Cannot import react-tap-event-plugin with from node_modules typescript

Tags: module, typescript

I am trying to learn react and typescript. And would like to include [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) in my project. From there homepage I am instructed to install react-tap-event-plugin, which I did and "node_modules/react-tap-event-plugin" does exist!

Now I am supposed to to do this:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

but the typescript compile tells me, that it cannot find the module.

I tried different variants (using require, importing node_mdules/...), but nothing worked.

How do I set this up correctly?

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "fbjs": "^0.2.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "0.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a d.ts file(s) in the node_modules folder too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install [definition file (.d.ts)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react-tap-event-plugin) for **react-tap-event-plugin**. You can do it with [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) by executing the following :

- if you don't have `typings` installed `npm install typings --global`
- `typings install dt~react-tap-event-plugin --save`

Also, be sure to reference `typings/index.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: The command is outdated. We should install typings like this: `typings install dt~react-tap-event-plugin --save`